# windows vnc via ssh to kvm guest - connection failed

Tags: kvm-virtualization, vnc, ssh-tunnel, centos6

I've a headless CentOS6 running KVM and I want to configure a guest via vnc. The problem is my working machine is Win7.

I created a guest using command:

```
sudo virt-install --name=c6-64 --disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/images/c6-64,size=8 --vnc --vcpus=1 --ram=1024 --cdrom=/tmp/CentOS-6.0-x86_64-bin-DVD1.iso --os-type=linux --os-variant=rhel6
```

So the vnc is listening on 127.0.0.1:5900.

No I want to connect to the vnc from Win7 machine. I tunnel 5900 from localhost to the server using putty, ssh connection is successful. However, when I try to connect using ultravnc or realvnc connection gets refused and in /var/log/secure on the server I can only see:

```
error: connect_to 10.0.0.2 port 5900: failed.
```

Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong? I just need to connect to the guests without installing vnc server inside them and only ssh access is not sufficient (windows guests too).

Thank you for any idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"So the vnc is listening on 127.0.0.1:5900"

The vnc should probably be listening on the IP of the headless Cent host.

Comment: Mea culpa! I tunneled to the wrong adress. I should have tunneled to 127.0.0.1:5900 not 10.0.0.2:5900. It works now.

Comment: Good deal... Glad it worked out.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Xming](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/) and SSH with [putty using X forwarding](http://www.math.umn.edu/systems_guide/putty_xwin32.html).  Then on the server, run `vncviewer 127.0.0.1:5900`, and it will forward that to your Windows 7 machine and give you a VNC window.

That way, you don't have to forward multiple ports for multiple VMs, since the VNC client will be running on the server.